# how to print an empty 2d array without getting a nullpointerexception

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am relatively new to `Java` and for a school project I need to print a 2D array. The base for this project is to print it with values `null`. But I can't put this into a for loop without getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Can anybody help?

```
private int ROWS;
private int COLUMNS;
private int WIDTH;

private String[][] sheet;
private String[][] values;
private int precision;

public SpreadSheet(int rows, int cols, int width, int precision) {
    this.ROWS = rows;
    this.COLUMNS = cols;
    /*this.WIDTH = width;
    this.precision = precision;*/
}

public void printSheet(){
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sheet[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(sheet);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

The main :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DemoSpreadSheet {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    SpreadSheet sh = new SpreadSheet(4, 6, 15, 2);
    sh.printSheet();
}

}
```

Comment: You do not initalize your array values, i.e., you have to assign a String to each cell of your two-dimensional array. Also you have to print `sheet[i][j]` instead of simply `sheet`. Edit: Nevermind the first part, I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: You probably want to print elements, not the whole array: `System.out.println(sheet[i][j]);`

Comment: How is this even possible?...you have not given any size/length to your array.You array object is not created!!! You have just declared a reference but that reference is not pointing towards any array object.

Comment: You could use a foreach loop also. `for (String[] row : sheet) { for (String col : row) { print(col); } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a small change to the SpreadSheet function:

```
public SpreadSheet(int rows;int cols;int width;int precision)
    {
      this.Sheet=new String[rows][cols];
      /*creates an array with 4 rows and 6  columns..(assuming this is what you wanted to do)*/
      }
```

There is also an error in your print sheet function:

```
System.out.println(Sheet); //illogical
 /*sheet does not print the content of the array Sheet*/
```

Change this to:

```
System.out.println(Sheet[i][j]);
/*this will print null */
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialisé your arrays.

```
sheet = new String[rows][cols]
```

This is an exemple you have other errors in you class.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it (including better format):

```
public void printSheet(){
     for (int i = 0; i < sheet.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < sheet[i].length; j++) {
             System.out.print(sheet[i][j] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
}
```

However, you have not assigned a length to your sheet. That means, at some point (at the constructor most likely) you have to define:

```
sheet = new String[rows][cols];
```

Comment: ok, thanks! I found a way in wich it works. The formatting also helps a great deal.